# Сможет ли выдержать TP-LINK Archer C7 нагрузку в 80 клиентов при использовании его в качестве DHCP сервера+NAT?

Tags: lan, dhcp, tp-link

Добрый день!
В офисе установлен коммутатор провайдера к которому подключены 3 TP-LINK Archer C7 и уже они через wi-fi подключены клиенты (30 моноблоков, 10 ноутбуков, 10 принтеров и 30 смартфонов). 
Теперь же мы хотим перевести основную массу клиентов на провод, для чего был закуплен коммутатор. Планируется следующая схема: коммутатор провайдера, далее 1 TP-LINK Archer C7 в качестве DHCP сервера+NAT. Далее наш коммутатор, к которому подключены моноблоки и принтеры. В этот же коммутатор подключены оставшиеся 2 TP-LINK Archer C7 для смартфонов и ноутбуков. Канал 100 Мбит/с
Сможет ли выдержать основной TP-LINK такую нагрузку?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Выдержит, если торрентами или IPTV никто увлекаться не будет. DHCP сервер нагрузку, почти что, не создает, программных ограничений на количество NAT сессий и активных соединений нет, процессора с головой хватит, тем более что NAT, частично, аппаратно реализован. Если отключить Wi-Fi и неиспользуемые сервисы (igmp proxy, smb, принт-сервер), то и греться сильно не будет, у этих роутеров нет радиаторов и  с перегревом бывают проблемы.
У меня как-то на работе Микротик приказал долго жить, а ЗИП подготовить забыли, поставил временно TP-Link из 1000-ой серии (какой именно не скажу, он без корпуса был, разобранный, но процессор в 2 раза медленее чем у Вашего и памяти в 2 раза меньше) и никто из 70+ работников разницы при работе в интернете не заметил. Канал у нас 50 Мбит был, но нагрузка больше от количества пакетов в секунду зависит, а не от толщины канала.
Но если есть возможность, то лучше ставить что-то по-функциональнее и в настройках более гибкое, а то с домашними TP-Link особо не разгуляешься.